# How to Show Table Entry Name Instead of id on Show or Index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok.  Asked this question yesterday and since started a whole new rails app to see if starting from scratch helps.

Here's how this app works.  A user will create a new countertop and enter their zip code, the countertop size and the type of countertop.  Possible countertop types are stored in a model called "Countertype".  Users select the countertype through a collection_select method, which lists all the entries in the Countertype table.  The responses to this Countertop form are saved in a Countertop table, which has a "countertop_id" integer column.

When the user lands on the Show and then the Index page, I'd like the name of the countertype to be visible instead of the integer.

How do I do this?  It's killing me.

Here's my schema:

```
create_table "countertops", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "counterzip"
 t.string   "countersize"
 t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
 t.integer  "countertype_id"
end

create_table "countertypes", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Here's my index and show

```
def index
 @countertops = Countertop.all
 @countertops = Countertop.includes(:countertype).all
end

def show
 @countertops = Countertop.all
 @countertops = Countertop.includes(:countertype).all
end
```

Countertop.rb:

```
class Countertop < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :countertype
end
```

Countertype.rb

```
class Countertype < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :countertop
end
```

Show:

```
<p>
  <strong>Counter Type:</strong>
  <%= @countertop.countertype.name %>
</p>
```

Index:

```
<% @countertops.each do |countertop| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= countertop.counterzip %></td>
    <td><%= countertop.countertype.name %>
```

Here's a readout from my console for both tables.

```
Countertop.last
  Countertop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countertops".* FROM "countertops"  ORDER            BY "countertops"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Countertop id: 1, counterzip: "19111", countersize: "100", created_at:    "2015-10-01 20:44:29", updated_at: "2015-10-01 20:44:29", Countertype_Id: 1> 
2.2.1 :029 > 

Countertype.last
 Countertype Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "countertypes".* FROM "countertypes"  ORDER BY "countertypes"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  => #<Countertype id: 1, name: "Granite", created_at: "2015-10-01 20:15:12", updated_at: "2015-10-01 20:15:12">
```

Heres's the error message:
    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: countertypes.countertop_id: SELECT  "countertypes".* FROM "countertypes" WHERE "countertypes"."countertop_id" = ? LIMIT 1

Changing the show to <%= @countertops.countertype_id %> displays a "1".

What do I need to fix to have it display "Granite" instead of "1" ??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have your associations backwards in the two models.  `belongs_to` should be listed in the model whose table contains the association column (countertype_id in this case).  `has_one` relies on the associated model to have this column.

A couple additional observations:

- According to the output from `Countertop.last`, `Countertype_Id` has uppercase characters.  This might not cause immediate problems with sqlite, but it may be worth changing to avoid any future problems, as Rails will assume column names are always downcased unless explicitly told otherwise.
- Your #show controller method has `@countertops` defined (plural), but the show view uses just `@countertop`.

Comment: Thanks!! Switching the association fixed it.  Although I'm not exactly sure why.